# Failure to parse POSIXct with lubridate

Tags: r

I have a dateTime column which I import as a factor. I want to convert this to a date

The imported column looks like this:

```
Wed May 23 00:00:00 CEST 2012
```

and sometimes like this

```
Mon May 12 00:00:00 CET 2014
```

and i want to convert it to a date like dmy (although I'm not fussed as to the exact format)

I have tried using lubridate:

```
data$VisitDate<-as.character(data$VisitDate)
parse_date_time(data$VisitDate, orders="abd hmsy")
```

but I get the error:

```
   Warning message:
    All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Comment: Try `"abdHMSY"`

Comment: What is your `locale` setting?

Comment: Having the time zone in the middle of the string is the problem.  `as.POSIXct(VisitDate, format="%a %B %d %H:%M:%S CEST %Y")`  kind of works but then the timezone is fixed.  as.POSIX can't read it, %Z is only for output.  I am not sure about lubridate.

Comment: You could try the anytime package.

Comment: OK so in the end I converted it to a string, got rid of CEST and CET using gsub and then used "abdHMSY". It was a combination of isses that needed sorting

Comment: It's a pretty non-standard format so [anytime](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html) would not have help either.  Having the timezone info in there is usually lethal.  Stick with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats whenever you can...

Comment: OK thanks for that. Will do in the future...